# Oracle INSERT INTO with select and values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert some values into a table from a select statement and some hardcoded values, but I'm not sure what the syntax would be. When I try I get an error saying there are not enough values so I know it's not reading my select statement correctly. Any help is appreciated.

```
insert into INSERT_STG
values(
  (select code,
          acct,  
          to_char(sysdate, 'mmddyy'),
          amt      
  from schema.table),
  'Partners',
  'city',
  'st',
  'Y',
  null,
```

);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
insert into INSERT_STG
  (select code,
          acct,  
          to_char(sysdate, 'mmddyy'),
          amt ,
  'Partners',
  'city',
  'st',
  'Y',
  null
  from schema.table);
```

Problems:

- You had extra comma  after null
- You can't combine hardcoded values and the select like you did.  The hard coded values have to be generated as part of the select.

This should work assuming: INSERT_STG has 9 columns of the datatypes in schema.table in the order of the select and string and support null on last column.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I just wasn't sure how all of that worked in pl/sql.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the "values" line and ensure you're inserting the same count of values as the table  `INSERT_STG` has. Otherwise, explicitly specify columns of target table to insert.